# How to associate a username from the User model to another model in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I currently have an index view with several input tags for a name, file and tags.
I'm trying to connect the model that handles that view (name: Uploaded) to the User model and associate the logged in users username to the Uploaded model.

Here's my view:

```
def index(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = FileUploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
else:
    form = FileUploadForm
allTags = Tag.objects.all()
context = {'form': form, 'allTags': allTags}
return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

and here's the Uploaded model:

```
class Uploaded(models.Model):
objects: models.Manager()
user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="users")
name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
file = models.FileField(upload_to=MEDIA_ROOT)
tags = TaggableManager()

def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.name} {self.file}"
```

Comment: Note that `objects: models.Manager()` has no effect, it should be `objects = models.Manager()`, so with `=` instead of `:`.

Comment: I found that on Stack Overflow as a solution to the Model.objects problem. The objects part was highlighted in PyCharm and was giving me an error. The solutions seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can "patch" the `.instance` wrapped in the form with the logged in user:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FileUploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.user = request.user
            form.save()
    else:
        form = FileUploadForm()
    allTags = Tag.objects.all()
    context = {'form': form, 'allTags': allTags}
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to a view to authenticated users with the
> [**`@login_required`** decorator [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator).

Comment: Thank you, this seems to work. I first tried using it and I added a user field in the form I was using but it seems that it doesn't work that way. After I removed the user field, it worked.